# Confidence interval - computing task

Tags: confidence-interval

I'm planning to write a small app for a tedious task:

- Generating pdf based on a existing template (.txt basically)
- Binding
  specific data (some text, recipient, etc) to that template

Suppose I have 100 pdf to generate. I expect $±100$% confidence if I check manually all the generated pdf.

- How many pdf should I check to reach a level of confidence of $95$%,
  $99$%, $99,999$%?
- What additional parameter should I deal with?

At first sight, checking only a few could give me a high confidence of reliability. However I'm wondering how to rigorously achieved such confidence using a proper formula.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [This earlier thread should answer your question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275112/calculating-confidence-interval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find several ways of calculating confidence intervals, wich I'm talking about. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

I calculate confidence intervals for probability that your program works properly. Here a my results for different types of one-sided 95% confidence intervals, if you check 100 out of 100.

```
Jeffrey (0.97525, 0.99999)
Agresti-Coull (0.9555, 1.0074)
Direct stepped binomial test (0.96244, 1)
Wilson (0.96300, 1.0)
Beta (0.96378, 1.0)
```

**Edit**

These estimates are for the *probability that your program works correctly for the random document from the infinite set of possible documents*, considering 100 of 100 has been processed correctly.

I've calculated these intervals with python library statmodels using fuction proportion_confint.

If you want confidence intervals for the *probability, that your program will work for 100 of 100*, having that it has worked for $x$ of $x$, that would be more difficult to calculate. The results for different documents may be highly correlated. Though if we consider them independent, we can go by the following algorithm:

1. choose the confidence level $c$.
2. calculate $c' = c^{1/(100-x)}$
3. calculate the lower bound $lb$ for probability of success of one calculation with the algorithms mentioned above on the level $c'$.
4. the resulting interval is $(lb^{100-x}, 1)$

For example for $x = 80$ and $c=0.95$, the resulting interval would only be $(0.1846, 1)$. With increasing $c$ and decresing $x$, the $lb$ will only get smaller.  Because this is the confidence interval for the probability that *all* $(100-x)$ of your calculations would be successful.

Comment: I don't understand. If I check 100 out of 100, my confidence is 100%. How can I calculate each intervals in the results you mentioned?

Comment: @roland For what value do you want to estimate the confidence intervals? I propose estimates for the probability that your programm works correctly for the random document from the infinite set of possible documents, considering 100 of 100 have been processed correctly.

Comment: I cannot get 0.78. What I did: (0.8  exp (1/20)) exp 20 = 0.80

Comment: @roland You're right, I miscalculated. I calculated confidence level $c' = 0.95^{1/20} = 0.99744$. Than for exact stepped interval (you can find it here. Confidence level is at the bottom, don't miss it http://statpages.info/confint.html) $lb = 0.91899$ and than interval lower bound is $lb^{20} = 0.1846$. But as I said the interval gives estimate for independent results, and in reality they are highly dependent and result would be much higher.